# How to do texture box mapping with blending in Blender Internal

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to do box mapping of texture with blending just like the node setting in Cycles below.

[image]
This is the texture I used

[image]

I could have used box mapping option on Blender Internal too but I couldn't have found blending option.
[image]

Is there way to do it easily? or I have to do some complicated node setting to do this? I guess it's possible to do this by using nodes but I can't come up with how.

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to do, but in Blender Internal the blending options are on the bottom of the influence tab.

Comment: Blending in box mapping is combining 3 textures projected from 3 direction by using face normal.

Comment: in the upper screenshot there's 1 image only. How do you map other 2? and btw which images are those? can you show them? I can't get it...

Comment: I added the picture of the texture I used. As you can see on material setting on Cycles, On image texture node, it's set to "Box", instead of flat. It will automatically project the same texture from 3(6 with negative direction) directions.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is in the node set up in the first image, the image texture node. It uses "box" projection, with the blend is set to 1.000. This was a feature added specifically for the purpose of blending the image being projected from all directions (even if that image is the same texture). 
The description provided in the blender 2.79 manual is here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html

Projection
Projection to use for mapping the textures.

Box
Maps the image to the six sides of a virtual box, based on the normal, using XY, YZ and XYZ coordinates depending on the side.

Blend
For Box mapping, the amount to blend between sides of the box, to get rid of sharp transitions between the different sides. Blending is useful to map a procedural-like image texture pattern seamlessly on a model. 0.0 gives no blending; higher values give a smoother transition.